# Why do we only check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime? Can't we use cube root?

Tags: primes, square-root

If a number n can be written as axb and m=sqrt(n). Here n=m*m. We say we only need to check upto m because min(a,b)<=m. So cant we take cube roots? Suppose we take n=21, then n=1x3x7. But Cube root is 2. Why does this method fail?

Comment: Put this question on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: there are lots of duplicates: [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5811151/995714), [Why we can use sqrt(n) instead of n/2 as an upper bound while finding prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383349/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr)

Answer (score 1):

Consider *n* = 143 = 11 * 13. The cube root of 143 is between 5 and 6. If you only test divisibility by the primes up to 6, you will not find either of the two factors of *n* and will mistakenly conclude that 143 is prime.