# Why do we check i <= sqrt(n) to find if a number is prime or not?

Tags: primes, primality-test

I know this question has been answered before, but I didn't quite understand the explanation that was given on that question.

I was doing the 30 days of code on HackerRank, and one of the exercises was to check whether a number is prime or not. Unfortunately, I was not capable of doing it by myself, so I checked the given solution after many attempts. Even after looking at the solutions, I can't understand one of the lines:

```
// Check for primality using odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(n)
for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2){
    // n is not prime if it is evenly divisible by some 'i' in this range
    if( n % i == 0 ){ 
        isPrime = false;
    }
}
```

Why is `sqrt(n)` used in the `for` loop?

Comment: What was the explanation that you have read? What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: consider a number larger than the square root, what would have to be true about its counterpart if it were a factor of the overall number?  then consider one equal to the square root

Comment: Take some particular n, for example n = 101. To make sure it's prime you have to make sure it's not divided by any number from 2 to 100. Now, what if you just check only odd numbers from 3 to 99? And finally, what if you just check odd numbers from 3 to 9? Do you need to check numbers starting 11 or it's enough and you can say 101 is prime?

Comment: The result of dividing `n` by any factor will be another factor.  so for any factor `f`, the value `n/f` is another factor.    If `f` is greater than the square root of `n`, then `n/f` must be less than the square root of `n`.

Comment: there are lots of duplicates: [Why do we check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5811151/995714), [Why we can use sqrt(n) instead of n/2 as an upper bound while finding prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21383349/995714), [Why do we only check up to the square root of a prime number to determine if it is prime? Can't we use cube root?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41530090/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose `n` is a composite number.

Then, `n = ab` where `a` and `b` both are between `1` and `n`.

If `a > sqrt(n)` and `b > sqrt(n)`, then this means that `ab > sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)` which basically implies that `ab > n`, this contradicts the assumption that `ab = n`.

Hence, either one factor (`a` or `b`) must be less than `sqrt(n)`, or both be equal to it. So if `n` is composite, `n` must have a prime factor `p <= sqrt(n)`